# Vscode integrated terminal accentuation not working?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, integrated

I'm experiencing an issue on Vscode version 1.49.2, and that's not the first time that this is happening.

The accentuation on my vscode just stopped to work. I'm from Brazil, I need to type things like "Área de Trabalho", "Helicóptero", on the integrated terminal, but he just ignore that. If I type the accent and then hit space, it will work well, but will not accentuate the word.

I have read one by one configuration on vscode to try to solve that problem but nothing works. Someone have a solution for this case?

Thank's!